# can I call an app in OpenFrameworks something other than testApp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openframeworks

I am working with OpenFrameworks for the first time (I am also rusty at C++).

I am trying to build an app with OFX, and I want to call my app something other than testApp.  I am building off the openCVExample code, and I've replaced testApp everywhere with the new name and moved the files from `testApp.{h,cpp}` to `newname.{h,cpp}`.

However, when I try to build (using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, if that makes a difference) I see that the `testApp.cpp` file is being generated with the contents of `newname.cpp` and put into my src/ folder.  I'm also getting griped at by the build saying that testApp isn't a valid namespace on all lines in `newname.cpp` where I am trying to call or define member functions (I am using `newname::functionName`).

I've looked at the build commandline, and it doesn't seem to be looking for `testApp.cpp`; I've also looked through the linker and other stuff, but don't see it mentioned anywhere in there.  Is this some bizarre feature of OpenFrameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the openframeworks directory there is a project creator app that will do this for you.

D:\workspace\of_v0073_vs2010_release\projectGenerator\projectGenerator.exe

It will also setup addons you've downloaded.

Note:: It creates solutions for VS 2010, i assume this can be opened by Express?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the instances of "testApp" to "newname" in a handful of places:

1. In testApp.h you'll need to change your app's class name. This is probably the 5th line, which looks like `class testApp : public ofBaseApp`
2. In testApp.cpp, you'll need to change all of the function definitions to use the "newname" namespace. These are all of the lines which look like `void testApp::setup()`
3. In main.cpp, you'll need to change the argument in `ofRunApp()` from `new testApp()` to `new newname()`

You actually *don't* have to change the names of the files from testApp.{h,cpp}, though it's still a good idea from an organization standpoint.

Comment: I did all this, and still I'm getting the generated file?  I basically just ran a find/replace on the whole project to change from testApp to newname everywhere it occurred.  I'm still confused how it could generate the file, even if I had forgotten to do those things.